# Increase rev limit with COBB AccessPort on EcoBoost platforms

Tags: ford

Is there a known way to increase redline with COBB AccessPort on EcoBoost platforms?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm sure with tuning, anything is possible.